# psr-4 autoload - cannot redeclare class

Tags: php, laravel-4, psr-4

I'm trying to use psr-4 autoload for the first time with Laravel. After I do that with models and I have the following eloquent model:

```
<?php namespace Models\Series;

class Player extends \BaseModel {}
```

It works fine, but if I add a collection like this:

```
public static function listing()
{
    return Player::paginate(15);
}
```

Then I receive this error:

`Cannot redeclare class Models\Series\Player`

I also tried replacing `Player::paginate(15)` with `self::paginate(15)`, but for no avail.

Comment: Instead of `composer dump-autoload -o` I ran `composer dump-autoload` and I don't receive the error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using static function in your model, why dont you just try using scope

```
namespace Models\Series;

class Player extends \BaseModel {

    public function scopeListing($query){
        return $query->paginate(15);
    }
}
```

i havent tested yet, but i hope i'll help :D

Comment: I appreciate your tip, but I was trying to fix the `Cannot redeclare class Models\Series\Player` error.